# Image position overlays content on resize

Tags: css

I have an image and content side by side with the image positioned absolute to the left edge of the viewport and then a column of content. When I resize the browser, the image stays in place and eventually covers the content.

Is it possible to force the image to "push" to the right so that it moves left, out of the viewport as I resize? I can't change the HTML so I am forced to use the existing code.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1230px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;  
}

.content-wrap {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

.floating-image {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 0;
width: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
max-width: 350px;
}

.floating-image img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="" class="row-wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrap ">
      <h2>ABOUT US</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque accumsan porta ultrices. Quisque tincidunt felis tellus, vel pharetra nisi condimentum vitae. Etiam mollis scelerisque leo, sed posuere tortor vulputate ut. Aliquam sed nisi id tortor euismod volutpat. Praesent laoreet dictum elit. Donec placerat blandit eleifend. Pellentesque molestie metus mi. Nullam eleifend venenatis imperdiet. Suspendisse egestas lorem eu turpis sollicitudin hendrerit. Aenean ultricies ultrices tortor, at efficitur mi dapibus eu. Donec ut pharetra sapien.</p>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="alignment-wrap text-left">
      <div class="img-wrap floating-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/750">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to hide the image when the size of the window is below specified length.

So maybe try something like this:

```
@media (max-width: [desired width]px) {
  .floating-image img {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not looking to hide the image until a much smaller breakpoint though.

Comment: So specify whatever width you want in the `[desired width]` part of the code. If you want it to be 300px then set it to 300.

Comment: Thanks but media queries is not the answer I am looking for.